# jQuery .get() function only works in debugger mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging

I'm trying to get data from http://numbersapi.com/random/, which will give you a plain text response, and save it to a variable for later use. Here's my javascript code:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var dataCopy = "not successful";
    $.get('http://numbersapi.com/random/', function(data) {
        dataCopy = data;
    });

    console.log(dataCopy);
}
```

where myFunction() is activated by a button.

dataCopy is logged in the console as "not successful" rather than the data from the API every time. Oddly enough, if I place a debugger statement as the first line of myFunction(), use my browser's debugger, and step over the lines very slowly, then myFunction() will work as intented. Stepping over the lines quickly will result in the previously mentioned error.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to remedy it? I'm new to getting information from APIs (I've only just heard of them), and I figured out this code from information pieced together from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

The ***$.get*** method is asynchronous so you may use [then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) like in:

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  var dataCopy = "not successful";
  $.get('http://numbersapi.com/random/', function(data) {
    dataCopy = data;
  }).then(function() {  // wait for get and then do your stuff
    console.log(dataCopy);
  });

}
myFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would dataCopy still contain data's value after exiting .then() ?

Answer (score 0):

You're logging `dataCopy` before the get call returns.  In debugging mode, maybe the event stuntman nature of get is different.

Move the console log call into the anonymous function if you want to log the value after the call.